# MySqlDataAdapter failed to retrieve data on the first load

Tags: asp.net, mysql, ajax, sqldataadapter

I use MySQL Connector for ASP.NET to retrieve data from my MySQL server. Everything seems to work fine, but just at the first asynchronous postback of my page, MySQLDataAdapter does not fill my DataSet. After a complete refresh the data is succesfully loaded by asynchronous postback.

I try to assign a bigger value to the command timeout, but it does not seem seem to work.

This does not happen locally, only on the production server.

I have checked that the fill does not work by displaying the request string and also by on each async postback (displaying the count() of my DS.table[0].rows).

This is really the fill method not working.

```
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(_connexionString))
            {
                string requete = "";
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();

                requete = "SELECT * from MYTABLE";

                using (MySqlDataAdapter MSDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(requete, conn))
                {
                    DS.Clear();
                    MSDA.Fill(DS);
                }
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            l_error.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: are you displaying this data using any data control? If you are using updatepanel change it to conditional mode and call updatepanelid.update after you bind data to page on postback.

Comment: Why do you dispose 'conn' instance if you use 'using' statement?

Comment: thinking that no dispose...a try to resolve..

Answer (score 2):

Try putting code into Page_Init event too.

Comment: the code that i have post is included in a function which is called on page_load but i will test in page_Init

Answer (score 0):

did you checked `Page.isPostBack`  property ?  may be you are not checking isPostback, properly. it would be helpful,if you share your entire method.

```
 if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   //load your datasets and data - adapters.
}
```

Comment: My function which to retrieve data was named "FillDSData" is called in page_load for the first loading of my page, then all my controls are contained in a updatepanel and each of this launch an asynchronous postback to call  the function "FillDSData". This is the first asynpostback which fail.

Answer (score 0):

After few investigation in code, i found that it not work, in fact an value of request was empty ... so no data return by mysql server, there was session key which was expire...
thx all for your help !